# Rerendering mapped array based on order

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

So I have an array of objects that I need to display in a specific order and be able to organize. The functionality is there and it works, but I can't get it to render appropriately.

Basically I have:

```js
const [objects, setObjects] = useState([]);

return (
  <>
    {objects.map(object =>
      <Component
        object={object}
      />
    )}
  </>
);
```

Now I obviously have this array filled with data and it renders fine, but when I try to reorganize the array, nothing seems to change on the UI.

I'm reorganizing by way of splice. I identify the object that I'm moving, splicing it out and splicing it back in at a different index (not actually sure if I need this temporary variable):

```js
function reorganize(sourceIndex, targetIndex){
  const object = objects[sourceIndex];
  const temp = objects;
  temp.splice(sourceIndex, 1);
  temp.splice(targetIndex, 0, object);
  setObjects(temp);
}
```

When I use console.log() on objects, I can see that the order has changed. But as I said, nothing changes on the UI. Any thoughts on how to make this work?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the reorganize function change this

```
const temp = [...objects];
```

Don't forget that it is an array.

Answer (score 0):

You are mutating the state - temp is not a copy of objects, but is still directly referencing it. In React you should not directly mutate the state - correct code would be `temp = [...objects]`. Also be aware that this will only create a shallow copy - if you are handling deeply nested arrays / objects, use an external library like Lodash's cloneDeep.